# How to know which model instance is committed in Django function transaction on_commit?

Tags: django, database, transactions

I want to do somethings after the a model instance is committed to database. But the transaction on_commit() does not have any variable related to the instance was saved? Is there any way to know that? Thnkas

Answer (score -1):

Django signals is the way to go.

As for your usecase, we can use the *post_save* signal to trigger a python function once a model's save() function has been called.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

def handle_change(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    ....

post_save.connect(handle_change, sender=User)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save

Comment: Django signal cannot cover my case. I tried. Problem I met with signal is that the transaction hadn't yet committed to database while I need query that data at that time